# Navigation Bar without effects for 1 second when page loads

Tags: jquery, css

I purchased a theme.

> http://transport.themesun.com/

When we load the home page, the navbar appears without effects for 1 second and then disappears. I don't know what's causing the issue.

[image]

I tried to place all the scripts in header as well but the issue still persists. Can any1 guide me? You can open the above link and press `Ctrl F5` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that navbar becomes hidden only  when some css classes (`.mm-menu.mm-offcanvas`) are applied but these classes are applied only when jquery plugin ( jquery.mmenu.min.all.js ) file is loaded and plugin is triggered. You can hide navabr by default in css:

```
#mobile-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

## Answer update:

Instead of using id to style element you should use a class. ID selectors have high specifity so they take precedence over class selectors and in your case visibility styles applied by the jquery plugin can be overridden and as a result navbar may not be visible even on mobiles. You can also use `:not` pseudo class (even with id selector):

```
#mobile-menu:not(.mm-menu) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the help I will check your solution.

Comment: In this case I think it would be best to add '.hidden' class (`.hidden { display: none;}`) and remove it after `jquery.mmmenu.min.all.js` file do it's job (small script fired after document ready). Otherwise you'll probably end with no mobile menu on mobile devices.

Comment: It's also good solution but please note that even if this class is not removed it will be overriden by classess added by `mmenu` plugin.

Comment: Thankyou all for the help. :)